# Detailed video lecture that gives in-depth explanation of the intuition behind Fibonacci Heaps operations

Tags: self-learning, resource-request, databases

I was going through the text *Introduction to Algorithms* by *Cormen et. al.* but faced some issues with the Fibonacci Heap section, especially the intuitive working of the charging and discharging of the potential function. When is the charging triggered or when is the discharging triggered. Without a proper a guidance ( I am doing self study) it is quite difficult for me to understand the details behind this specific topic on my own.

I had asked few of my questions [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/128411/essence-of-the-cost-benifit-obtained-by-using-markings-in-fibonacci-heaps-by) and [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/128410/intuition-behind-the-entire-amortized-concept-of-fibonacci-heap-operations) but while writing this question, I haven't received an answer. Probably this means that topic is quite difficult (from the intuition and tear-down point of view, this is what I feel , may be others might differ).

Anyways, could anyone recommend me video lectures which shall instruct me and inculcate in me the intuition of the working of the Fibonacci Heap. It shall be very helpful me and other who are probably in need of the same.

Thank you.

Comment: I am not myself familiar with Fibonacci Heaps, but when I search for "Fibonacci Heaps" on Google, and then click on videos, I get many videos. Some are long and some are short and say that they are the main idea. Will those help you?

Comment: I do not quite know whether it shall help me. Let me go through a "long" video 1:17:00 length, of IMSc. While watching videos from youtube unless the source is known it is dangerous to go through them as some wrong source can teach me wrong concept, and once a concept is learnt it is difficult to forget. IMSc is a good source I feel. Thanks for the method of getting videos. @BenI

Comment: I've found in general that the shorter videos that are more edited are often better for the "big idea", and that the longer videos help with all of the details when you are ready to dive into them. Good luck!

Comment: @AbhishekGhosh: I'm not saying you're wrong, but your reticence about watching an educational video that has not been curated clashes with your expectation of education yourself through self-learning. Teachers and institutions specifically curate the source material to improve the quality of education, but that curation takes effort and therefore comes with a cost that self-learners specifically want to avoid.

Comment: @Flater I agree with you